# How to switch cameras to get a 360 degrees view on an object?

Tags: c++, opencv3.0, 360-degrees

I'm trying to find a way to switch between several cameras in different positions around an object, to get a 360 degrees view in real time using C++. I'm working with opencv and I succeeded to open all the cameras, but I couldn't find the documentation or a way to have that 360 degree fluent switch.

this is the code I made so far

```
 using namespace cv;
 using namespace std;


 int main(int argc, char* argv[])
 {


  int a = 0;
VideoCapture cap(0); // open the video camera no. 0
VideoCapture cap1(1);

//if (!cap.isOpened())  // if not success, exit program
//{
//  cout << "Cannot open the video cam" << endl;
//  return -1; 
//}

double dWidth = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH); //get the width of frames of the video
double dHeight = cap.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT); //get the height of frames of the video

cout << "Frame size : " << dWidth << " x " << dHeight << endl;

namedWindow("MyVideo", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); //create a window called "MyVideo"

while (1)
{
    Mat frame;

    bool bSuccess;
    if(a==0)
        bSuccess = cap.read(frame); // read a new frame from video
    else if (a == 1)
        bSuccess = cap1.read(frame);

    if (!bSuccess) //if not success, break loop
    {
        cout << "Cannot read a frame from video stream" << endl;
        break;
    }

    imshow("MyVideo", frame); //show the frame in "MyVideo" window

    if (waitKey(1) == 'a')
    {
        if (!a) a = 1;
        else a = 0;
    }
    /*else if (waitKey(1) == 27)
    {
        cout << "esc key is pressed by user" << endl;
        break;
    }
```

I have 6 other cameras, and an object in the middle
is it possible to do it in C++? or do I need to use something else. Keeping in mind that it has to be done in real time.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please include code of what you have tried so far and what you were able to accomplish. This will help to narrow down your problem.

Comment: I added my code, thank you for the remark.

Comment: You can use 3d reconstruction algorithms to get 360 view of the scene, take a look at it.

Comment: I found a software to reconstruct my images, but it's not in real time, and I also found some algorithms to manipulate the videos with c++ but it's complicated and not what I'm looking for. I just need a 360view over an object captured by several cameras around it.